# C Macro - variables types, how does it work?

Tags: c, macros

```
#define CHANGE_OP_MODE      0

#define SetID(ID)   (((unsigned char)ID << 8) | ((unsigned char)(CHANGE_OP_MODE)))

short x = 0;
char y = 1;

x = SetID(y);
```

Moving 8 bits causes the ID to be 0, so why is X == 1?

Comment: Are you sure you're getting `x == 1` and not `x == 256`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question has nothing to do with the fact that your shift operation is hidden inside a macro. Please adjust your question title. (The C Macro part also isn't needed, this is what the tags are for.)

Answer (score 1):

The bitshift operator is implicitly casting it's operands to `int`, regardless your explicit cast to `unsigned char`. So shifting left an `int` value of `1` by `8` will yield value of `2^8=256`. Which is actually the result that I am getting.

Comment: To get what seems to be the desired result, use `(unsigned char)(ID << 8)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your shifting becomes always zero. A char consits of 8 bit. So you push the value of ID with `<<8` outside of this field. The bits right of ID, whish becomes free, will fill up with zeros.